# Can I animate my mapView like with SatNav

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit, kml

I'm using MapKit to load a MKMapView and loading KML files to display a route with polylines between the designated points. I've seen a similar Android app using Google Maps that animates the route and runs it from start to finish.

I've been through the MapKit Framework documentation and I can't find anything that suggests I can do the same thing using Apple Maps.

If I'm wrong and it is possible I would be grateful for any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to resolve this issue is import the Google maps framework, which works perfectly well alongside MKMapkit.

There is a facility within Google Maps that enables the developer to animate their route.